# Enabling or disabling NIC remotely with windows 2008

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, netsh

I've been trying to enable or disable a NIC on Windows 2003 Server from a Windows 2008 Server PC. After googling around a bit, the command should be something like this:

```
netsh -r remotecomputer interface set interface "interface name" disabled
```

But when I try it, I get this error: "The newname and enable/disable option for LAN interfaces is not valid when administrating a remote machine".

I have admin access on both systems, and they are on the same LAN.

Anybody knows the right way to do it?

Comment: once you remotely disable it, how would you remotely enable it?

Comment: I think we're assuming that he's a good little administrator and has out of band access methods to get  back into it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's by design. You might want to try Psexec and the command "locally".

Comment: @Keltari as PsychoData said I have more than one NIC on the remote PC. I thought I could use one of the others to disable and bring back the one I need

Comment: @moses I was able to enable and disable the NIC using Psexec: `psexec.exe \\remotecomputer netsh interface set interface "interfacename" disabled` if you make it an answer I'll be glad to accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, turning off a [NIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) is disallowed when done remotely.

Running with [`Psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) essentially runs the command as a local user, to bypass this restriction.

> psexec.exe \remotecomputer netsh interface set interface "interfacename" disabled

If you need credentials:

> psexec.exe \remotecomputer -u username -p password netsh interface set interface "interfacename" disabled

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a "by design" feature to prevent you from locking yourself out. I remember running into a similar issue years ago.

Comment: This would make a good comment, but you don't provide any kind of a solution in this answer. [Once you have more rep](http://superuser.com/help/privileges) you will be able to comment on other questions